# Keep modal open after refresh using - Contextual routing and modal routes in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a simple NextJS app that has a button. When the button is clicked a modal is popped up. I'm using NextJS routing for modal routes.

When the modal is open and the user refreshes the browser, the user is taken away from the modal.

Is there a way in NextJS to reopen the model browser is refreshed on the model route.

```
// pages/index.js
import Link from "next/link";
import Modal from "react-modal";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <div>
      <Link href={`?country=spain`} as={`/country`}>
        <a>To Country</a>
      </Link>

      <Modal
        isOpen={!!router.query.country}
        onRequestClose={() => router.push(`/`)}
      >
        <p>Hello World</p>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

// pages/country.js
export default function Country() {
  return <div>country page</div>;
}
```

What I want is when the user refreshes the browser, the model should be reopened

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: You're going to need to track the modal's state in more permanent manner. Cookies or [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) are available.

Comment: @Ouroborus is there an example that shows how this can be done

Comment: you can try storing modal state in `sessionStorage`

Comment: @breaktop can you share code for both routes `/welcome` and `/welcome/modal/content1`

Comment: @NileshPatel Here is an example `https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-tesla-h5703?file=/pages/index.js` Ive updated with what an example

Comment: @breaktop please check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-matsumoto-vv86u?file=/pages/index.js) You are passing query string but want to navigate to `/country` not sure what you want to do